# Parsing a flat JSON array with no indice

Tags: java, android, json

I am scratching my head to figure out how to parse the following JSON object.

```
[
    {
        "result": true,
        "response": "Successfully got list of users in radius of 10km"
    },
    {
        "username": "elize",
        "photo": "http://www.embedonix.com/apps/mhealth/images/elize/elize.png"
    },
    {
        "username": "mario",
        "photo": "http://www.embedonix.com/apps/mhealth/images/mario/mario.png"
    }
]
```

This is I guess a single index json array. The first part tells that the operation of building the json object was ok.

Then there are pairs of `username` and `photo` which I have to parse them and put them in a list:

```
public class User {

    private String mName;
    private String mPhotoURl;

    public User(String name, String url)
    {
       ///
    }
}
```

So if the first entry of json is `result -> true` I should have a `ArrayList<User>`.

I tried to do the following but it always raises the JSONParse exception:

```
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
        int length = json.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            JSONArray obj = json.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(i));
            Log.i(TAG, i + " username: " + obj.getString(i));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);` your data is a JSONArray.

Comment: Hi, if the result object is always the first one, could u just remove it, validate if its true then parse the whole user list with the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize function. The other way is to always fix anything from second index to the end as {1,[1,2,3,4]} and serialize into your object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this way

```
 try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
            int length = jsonArray.length();

            for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i(TAG, i + " username: " + obj.getString("username"));
                Log.i(TAG, i + " photo: " + obj.getString("photo"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(i==0){
                    Log.i(TAG, i + " result: " + obj.getString("result"));
                    Log.i(TAG, i + " response: " + obj.getString("response"));
                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG, i + " username: " + obj.getString("username"));
                    Log.i(TAG, i + " photo: " + obj.getString("photo"));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Code...something like this..

```
          try {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
                int length = json.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {



                    JSONObject childObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(i==0){

                        String result = child.getBoolean("result");
                        String resp = child.getString("response");

                    } else {

                    String username = child.getString("username");
                    String photo = child.getString("photo");
                    Log.i(TAG, i + " username: " + username);
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```